# How to control whether or not to run a script in /etc/init.d/ when booting?

Tags: linux, boot, debian

I have several scripts in `/etc/init.d/`, and I'd like to choose to run one of them depending on some system parameters. What I can thing of is to add branch inside each script which causes it to exit when the condition is not satisfied. Are there better solutions?

Comment: Can you clarify what conditions do you mean?

Comment: IP address. The root filesystem will be shared by several devices, so each device will only run their corresponding (by IP address) script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After preamble (example)

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          FOO
# Required-Start:    $syslog $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     3 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Description:       Start FOO to allow XY and provide YZ
### END INIT INFO
```

and before start/stop/restart `case` you can set your logic to check IP's and exit or continue.

And this is IMHO best solution because it is native to `init` subsystem.

Comment: Looks great. Thank you!